# PHP, PCI compliance problem: How to?

Tags: php, pci-compliance

I've have a problem with the PCI compliance. Basically they want me to add `https://` on every page where the `password` field is present. this is kind of wierd.

My form in `index.php` looks like:

```
 <form method=post action="login.php" id="login">
 <input type="text" size="16" maxlength="30" name="login" id="login_user" />
 <input type="password" size=16 maxlength="20"  name="pass" class="ifield" id="login_pass"/>
 <input name="msubmit" type="submit" value="Login" />
 </form>
```

I've tried to post to https: `<form method=post action="https://test.com/login.php" id="login">` but the test it still fails.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: This is not just about adding the https:// prefix somewhere in the code, this is about actually *using* SSL. Are you familiar with that? Is it set up on your site?

Comment: You have to serve up the login page via SSL as well, not just submit to an ssl page. You'd be better off just serving up EVERYTHING via SSL, rather than jumping back and forth between regular and SSL pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you will need to configure your webserver to support SSL. You will need to purchase an SSL certificate and configure your webserver to answer requests on both port 80 and port 443.

After you have completed these changes, you will be able to tell your form to post to the SSL version of your site via the URL you posted above.

If the compliance rules require it, you may also need to make the form itself load under the SSL version of the site. In this case, you can update all of your links to the form to point to the 'https://' version, or modify your webserver rules to forward all requests for the form to the 'https://' version.

Answer (score -2):

From an objective security (not PCI) standpoint, there is nothing wrong with filling in the form as you have it, then posting it via SSL to an https address. Whether the page on which the blank form was originally displayed was a secure page is irrelevant, though many people think otherwise (wrongly). Presenting your form on a secure page is marketing -- people feel more comfortable when you do so. Submitting it via https is the actual secure part.

Many PCI-compliance requirements are hypothetical or about marketing and the perceptions of security, as opposed to actual security. If your scanner is flagging you simply because the form is being presented on a non-SSL page, then you could legitimately dispute that finding, as there is no security impact. If the form in question, even when properly accessed, doesn't allow access to server management or private information, then you could also legitimately dispute the finding. However, if the process of logging in allows access to personal information or server management, then there are multiple reasons to make sure that it is submitted via a secure port.

Comment: I strongly disagree. If the login form is served from HTTP, it's quite possible for a man-in-the-middle attack to change the HTML to point somewhere else (say, on the wireless at a coffee shop). If the login form is served over HTTPS, it's quite a bit more challenging to achieve.